# Usage of Range operator in Data.subdata

Tags: swift

In Swift 3, I wonder why I'm able to use the half-open range operator `..<` in [Data.subdata(in:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/data/1779918-subdata) but not the closed range operator `...`.

I've searched everywhere but can't understand why it gives me this error : 
*no '...' candidates produce the expected contextual result type
'Range' (aka 'Range')*

Here's an example of both the one that works and the one doesn't :

```
import Foundation

let x = Data(bytes: [0x0, 0x1])
let y : UInt8 = x.subdata(in: 0..<2).withUnsafeBytes{$0.pointee}
let z : UInt8 = x.subdata(in: 0...1).withUnsafeBytes{$0.pointee} // This fails
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your comment led me to a new search and I now understand after reading this : https://oleb.net/blog/2016/09/swift-3-ranges/.  If you'd like to write an answer, I'll gladly accept it.  I'm still a bit green with Swift so those don't jump out at me as obvious!  I wasn't aware that both operator returned different kind of "Ranges".

Comment: I have added an answer :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

- [`..<`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/1779470-..) is the *half-open* [range operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID73), which can either create a [`Range`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/range) or [`CountableRange`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/countablerange) (depending on whether the `Bound` is [`Strideable`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/strideable) with an `Integer` `Stride` or not). The range that is created is inclusive of the lower bound, but exclusive of the upper bound.
- [`...`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/1784375-...) is the *closed* range operator, which can either create a [`ClosedRange`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/closedrange) or [`CountableClosedRange`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/countableclosedrange) (same requirements as above). The range that is created is inclusive of *both* the upper and lower bounds.

Therefore as [`subdata(in:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/data/1779918-subdata) expects a `Range<Int>`, you cannot use the closed range operator `...` in order to construct the argument – you must use the half-open range operator instead.

However, it would be trivial to extend `Data` and add an overload that does accept a `ClosedRange<Int>`, which would allow you to use the closed range operator.

```
extension Data {
    func subdata(in range: ClosedRange<Index>) -> Data {
        return subdata(in: range.lowerBound ..< range.upperBound + 1)
    }
}
```

```
let x = Data(bytes: [0x0, 0x1])
let z : UInt8 = x.subdata(in: 0...1).withUnsafeBytes {$0.pointee}
```

Comment: Great! And thanks a lot for the detailed answer that includes an extension!

Comment: @droussel Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

At-risk of my comment being closed I'll speak out anyway - I followed the advice of a closed/deleted comment as the selected answer did not work with Swift 5. The working solution was:

`x.subdata(in: Range(0...1))`

I assume this has to do with interpretations of "Range" vs "NSRange" - but honestly I don't know.